# Disable "Are you sure you want to quit this application"

Tags: macos, terminal, shutdown

Sometimes if an application like iTerm or XAMPP is running, and I try to shut down my Mac, it prompts "Are you sure you want to quit this application". It then disables the shutdown process until I click "No" or "Yes". Is there a way to configure my settings to disable the prompt from showing up and interrupting shutdown?

Answer (score 1):

Did some [Research](https://discussions.apple.com/message/17261128#17261128#17261128) and it seems like you cannot disable the feature.

Although, there seems to be ways around it;

**From the link I provided:**

> Could just shut down using Control-Option-CMD-Eject.  This will quit open Applications instantly and shutdown gracefully -- or hold down the Option key while selecting Shutdown.

Let me know if that helps.